# как передать данные из listview в textview в android

Tags: java, android

В `ListView` выводится список из входящих СМС сообщений ("само сообщение", "номер телефона" ).

Дело в том, что когда я кликаю по пункту `ListView`на другое `Activity` передается только `id` номер строки, а хотелось бы, чтобы еще и текст передавался ("само сообщение").

Дорогие знатоки, подскажите в чем секрет?

Comment: вот если бы еще и код привели...

Comment: Куда передаётся id, там получайте его, и в соответствии с id выводите сообщения, подобно тому, как выводите их в listView

Answer (score 2):

Тут все очень просто.
1) Элементы списка listView должны быть объекты. У которых есть поля id, text.

2) В Адаптере нужно написать метод GetItem который будет получать этот объект по id.

3) В обработчике при клике, нужно вызывать этот метод и получать объект.

4) В передаваемое активити передавать полученный объект.

Вот в принципе и все) Ничего сложного.

**UPD.**

```
public Object getItem(int position) {
        return sms.get(position);
    }
```

Предопределенный метод который возвращает Object. Нужно приравнять его в твоему типу объекта или написать дополнительно в адптере.

```
SMS getSMS(int position){
        return ((SMS) getItem(position));
    }
```

Здесь в данном случае он вернет сообщение по позиции.

При клике обрабатывать так.

```
    listViewSong.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int position,
                                    long id) {

                Intent newIntent = new Intent(AlbumActivity.this, TextActivity.class);
SMS sms = adapter.getSMS(position) ;
                newIntent.putExtra("textSMS",sms.getTextSms);
                startActivity(newIntent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: теоретически я понимаю, практически, пишу такой код:
// обрабатываем клик по пункту:
  lvMsg.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,long id) {ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    // Create Draft box URI
String itemname = new Integer(position).toString(); // создаем новый intent  Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent3.setClass(this, simple.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("defStrID", itemname); // defStrID - номер нажатой строки
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent); // запускаем intent
   }

Comment: как getItem прикрутить? Можно маленький пример кинуть?
Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Обновил ответ, смотрите выше!